# JQuery UI Tabs size

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

i have a problem with the tab size in jquery UI , they are HUGE .. i changed a bit the css but cant find the propper id/class to fix it ..  :(

[image]

and the text inside the tab aslo changes size :S 
as always , any change is appreciated
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text size is defined in .ui-helper-reset by default, but it might be overriden by the CSS of the active theme. When in doubt, fire up Firebug and use the Inspect button to find out the CSS definitions for the element in question.

Answer (score 7):

modifying the `.ui-tabs` jquery ui theme class to include the `font-size` property will resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

I use `body {font-size:62.5%;}`

Answer (score 2):

I hope this question is similar to the question in [reducing the height of jquery ui tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698141/reducing-the-height-of-jquery-ui-tabs)..

From there i found this info to be useful for you..

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li {height: 25px; font-size:12px; }

Answer (score 1):

Just change padding property for `li a` element

i.e., by default padding property for `li a { padding:0.5em 1em;}`
You can override the above property to meet your requirement .

Answer (score 1):

There are some good ideas here:  http://keith-wood.name/uiTabs.html

Essentially, create a css class like this:

```
.my-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li { font-size: 10pt; }
```

Then use this class in your tab's :

```
<div id='divMyTabbedContainer' class='my-tabs'>
```